# How to replace elements of a matrix by an another matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How to replace elements of a matrix by an another matrix in MATLAB?

Ex: let say if we have a matrix A, where

`A=[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 1 0 1]`

I want to replace all ones by

`J=[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]`

and zeros by

`K=[0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0]`

So that I can get 9x9 matrix.  So how we will code it in MATLAB

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you might want to take a look at the [kronecker tensor product](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/kron.html).  This is not a general case but the idea should work for what you want

```
>> kron(A==1,J)+kron(A==0,K)

ans =

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

which, for the example case, would simplify to a simpler command:

```
>> kron(A,J)

ans =

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: I never thought of using `kron()` like that - even though I've used often enough it my own code. Very ingenious! take 10 geek points!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
A2=imresize(A,size(A).*size(J),'nearest');
J2=repmat(J,size(A));
K2=repmat(K,size(A));
A2(A2==1)=J2(A2==1);
A2(A2==0)=K2(A2==0)
```

Comment: Thanks you Oli. Appreciated your concern.